# Remove unnecessary configuration folders

Tags: arch-linux, maintenance, disk-cleanup

Many applications create a hidden folder in /home/user. I've tested many applications that I later uninstalled.

Is there a way to check which folders have been left behind in my home folder by applications no longer installed on the system?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, no. Removing user configuration folder should be part of the uninstall process but it's not.